# Post request on Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim

Could someone please help me?
I have this 500 error when making a post request... Can't understand what it is

**NOTE: If i run this api on from a rest client Chrome Extension it works Otherwise i get the following error...**

The application could not run because of the following error:
Details
Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Line:114

Routes:

```
<?php 
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/events','getEvents');
$app->get('/events/:year/:month', 'getMonth');
$app->get('/events/:year/:month/:day','getAllAfter');
$app->post('/events', 'addEvent');
$app->run();
```

This is My Function:

```
function addEvent() {

$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$request = $app->request();
$body = $request->getBody();
$event = json_decode($body);

//Line 114
$submited_date = $submited_date = $event->{'date_submit'} .' '.$event->{'time_submit'};   
$sql = "INSERT INTO events (edate, title, performers, address) VALUES (:edate, :title, :performers, :address)";
try {
    $conx = getconx();
    $stmt = $conx->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("edate", $submited_date);
    $stmt->bindParam("title", $event->etitle);
    $stmt->bindParam("performers", $event->performers);
    $stmt->bindParam("address", $event->address);
    $stmt->execute();
    $event->id = $conx->lastInsertId();
    $conx = null;
    $result = array("status"=>"success","events"=>$event);
    echo json_encode($result);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $result = array("status"=>"error","message"=>'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
    echo json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
}
```

This is the json sent:

```
{
   "date":"24 March, 2014",
   "date_submit":"2014-03-24",
   "time":"4:00 PM",
   "time_submit":"16:00:00",
   "etitle":"Event     Title",
   "performers":"david",
   "address":"Place"
}
```

jquery code:
**fixed by using JSON.stringify(); to the data before sending request**

```
     function addEvent(jsondat) {
            console.log('addEvent');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: rootURL,
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsondat); ,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    alert(Event created successfully');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('addEvent error: ' + textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
        jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
            jQuery('form#myForm').bind('submit', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var form = this;
                var pson = ConvertFormToJSON(form);
                //document.write(JSON.stringify(pson));
                addEvent(pson);
            });
        });
```

Comment: I marked it with a comment on the right

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump` of `$event` and `$body` to make sure you are getting back what you expect.

Comment: Just added those var_dump

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's line 114? Can you post the entire exception, including message in full and stack trace?

Comment: @Phil I've added the Trace

Comment: Do you get the same error when you have the `var_dump` statements in your code? I find it impossible to believe that you could see that dumped data and still get the same errors unless line 114 is not the one shown.

Comment: @Phil I added a note at the beginning on bold and it makes it even crazier...
Is this because i'm doing this locally? But if i use the chrome extension rest client, it works even locally ...

Comment: @Jazzvel Ignore that for now. Can you answer my question above? Do you get the same error when you can see the `var_dump` output? Can you update your question's code to include the `var_dump` statements?

Comment: No, just wasn't able to reply as fast as you wanted i guess
Why the Downvote? You mad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was found and it wasn't in my index.php
it was in the ajax request...
This was fixed by using JSON.stringify() to my serialized array.

That's why just in the rest client worked because the json there was sent correctly...
Thanks to Matt from slim framework support
http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/6789-not-able-to-handle-post-request